# Apply one jQuery to multiple span elements

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

everyone!
I am trying to apply one jQuery on multiple progress bar pies with different classes, but can't seem to manage. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class='zarade'>
    <span class="chart" data-percent="30"><span class="percent"></span></span>
    <span class="chart" data-percent="60"><span class="percent"></span></span>
    <span class="chart" data-percent="80"><span class="percent"></span></span>
    <span class="chart" data-percent="130"><span class="percent"></span></span>

</div>
```

And here is the .js portion:

```
<script src="js/easypiechart.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var chart = window.chart = new EasyPieChart(document.querySelector (".chart"), {
        easing: 'easeOutElastic',
        delay: 5000,
        size: 150,
        barColor: '#F30',
        trackColor: '#CCC',
        scaleColor: false,
        lineWidth: 6,
        trackWidth: 4,
        lineCap: 'butt',
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            this.el.children[0].innerHTML = Math.round(percent);
        }
    });

    document.querySelector('.js_update').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        chart.update(Math.random()*200-100);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: @HugoSousa I guess is that the OP is passing an array to the EasyPieChart func but it expects not an array but an object

Comment: @dariogriffo So, the problem is having multiple spans with `chart` class?

Comment: why dont you iterate the selector?